# contentsize and contentOffset equivalent in NSScroll view

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, uiscrollview, nsscrollview

I am porting an app from Ipad to mac. (I know that it sounds weird)

I stuck with NSScrollview. Please guide me contentsize , contentOffset  equivalent  in NSScrollview.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
UIScrollView* uiScroll;
uiScroll.contentSize;
uiScroll.contentOffset;
uiScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w,h);
uiScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

=

```
NSScrollView* nsScroll;
nsScroll.documentView.frame.size;
nsScroll.documentVisibleRect.origin;
nsScroll.documentView.frameSize = NSMakeSize(w,h);
[nsScroll.documentView scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(x,y)];
```

Or perhaps even better:

```
import AppKit

extension NSScrollView {
    var documentSize: NSSize {
        set { documentView?.setFrameSize(newValue) }
        get { documentView?.frame.size ?? NSSize.zero }
    }
    var documentOffset: NSPoint {
        set { documentView?.scroll(newValue) }
        get { documentVisibleRect.origin }
    }
}
```

Notes: I used 'documentSize' (and 'documentOffset') because 'contentSize' conflicts with an already existing property of NSScrollView.

Comment: `nsScroll.documentView.scrollPoint` is not available. It shall be `[nsScroll.documentView.scrollPoint NSMakePoint(x,y)]` instead.

Comment: @HarryNg Thanks, I recently modernized the syntax and created that mistake.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between the `UIScrollView.contentOffset` setter and `NSView.scroll(_:)`: the latter makes the scrollers flash. If anyone finds out how to not make them flash, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the lines from @aepryus, here are a couple more useful lines for getting/setting the scroll offset on macOS:

```
//Get the current scroll offset:
_contentViewOffset = scrollView.contentView.bounds.origin;

//Set the scroll offset from the retrieved point:
NSPoint scrollPoint = [scrollView.contentView convertPoint:_contentViewOffset toView:scrollView.documentView];
[scrollView.documentView scrollPoint:scrollPoint];
```

Answer (score -3):

Everything you need to know about `NSScrollView` is laid out in the [Scroll View Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Basics.html) provided in the documentation.

Although it doesn't appear that there's a direct equivalent, `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` can be likened to the size of `NSScrollView`'s `documentView`, which is the scrollable content provided as an `NSView` to `NSScrollView` with `setDocumentView:`.

`setContentOffset:` can be compared to `NSView`'s `scrollPoint:`, which uses an `NSPoint` to specify the offset of the `documentView` within the `NSScrollView`.

See the documentation for elaboration and code examples.