# Is there a current Scroll View Programming Guide for Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

The Mac Developer Library version of the Scroll View Programming Guide for Mac was last updated June, 2010.  The straightforward step-by-step instructions don't apply today.

I'm trying to port some code from iOS to Mac.  I've looked at the Migrating from Cocoa Touch section of the Mac Technology Overview.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457926/contentsize-and-contentoffset-equivalent-in-nsscroll-view) was useful.  And I found a [forum post at bignerdranch.com](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=189&t=7447) that supplied the critical tip to turn off Autolayout.

Are there recommendations for a good introduction to Scroll Views for Mac beyond the NSScrollView Class Reference?

Comment: Where in that particular guide do you get lost? Apple docs often don't have the latest screenshots or tidbits in it but should be correct in general. We might be able to help you out with a specific question..

Comment: I started looking for an alternative to that document after Creating a Scroll View in Interface Builder.  Choose Layout > Make subviews of > Scroll View.  I couldn't find the Choose Layout and I assumed (obviously, I suppose) it would update to Editor > Embed In > Scroll View.  But I don't want to second guess the guide if there's something more current available.  In particular Auto Layout seems to have changed the scroll view game.  I spent a fair amount of time debugging a simple example before I found that unchecking Use Auto Layout seemed to be the magic bullet.

Comment: My current app has lots of NSScrollViews and auto layout is on for most of the views. What problems are you having?

Comment: Could anyone please share the guide here? I would like to have a look at it too.

Comment: @AnanthKamath The guide appear to now be archived at <https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003221>